# Is it possible to use std::enable_if to select a member template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

Given a class declaration

```
class A {
    template <typename T> T foo();
};
```

I would like to specialize `A::foo` for various types (`int`, ...) and type classes (POD, non-POD) of `T`. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to use `std::enable_if` for the latter. The following doesn't compile:

```
template <> int A::foo<int>(); // OK

template <typename T> 
typename std::enable_if<is_pod<T>::value, T>::type foo(); // <<<< NOT OK!

template <typename T> 
typename std::enable_if<!is_pod<T>::value, T>::type foo(); // <<<< NOT OK!
```

The issue is probably due to the `std::enable_if<...>` stuff being part of the function signature, and that I did not declare any such member inside `A`. So how can I specialize a template member based on type traits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no reason to specialize here, overloading the function seems to suffice in my mind.

```
struct A
{
    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type foo()
    {
        std::cout << "integral" << std::endl;
        return T();
    }

    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type foo()
    {
        std::cout << "not integral" << std::endl;
        return T();
    }
}
```

When checking for POD or no POD, you only have these two choices, so a more generic function is not needed (and not allowed, because it would be ambiguous). You need more than that? You can check for explicit types without specialization with the help of `std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, T>::value, T>::type`.

Comment: @Daniel Gehriger `enable_if` was made for conditionally removing functions from overload resolutions, so pretty much for exactly this case.

Comment: Yes, but I still have the `A::foo<int>()` (and many other specializations for some specific types) which will conflict with whatever has been selected by `enable_if`.

Comment: My idea is to replace those with `template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, T>::value, T>::type foo() { /*...*/ }` which should have the same effect as your specialization and solves the conflicts

Comment: Right - but we then have to add negative assertions for all of them to the others that also match the type (`std::is_integral<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, int>::value`), correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I guess if you have a complex branched tree of decisions this could get very nasty.

Answer (score 4):

I'd just forward this to a structure, which does handle this well:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct FooCaller;

class A {
public:
    template <typename T>
    T foo() {
        // Forward the call to a structure, let the structure choose 
        //  the specialization.
        return FooCaller<T>::call(*this);
    }
};

// Specialize for PODs.
template <typename T>
struct FooCaller<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value>::type> {
    static T call(A& self) {
        std::cout << "pod." << std::endl;
        return T();
    }
};

// Specialize for non-PODs.    
template <typename T>
struct FooCaller<T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pod<T>::value>::type> {
    static T call(A& self) {
        std::cout << "non-pod." << std::endl;
        return T();
    }
};

// Specialize for 'int'.
template <>
struct FooCaller<int> {
    static int call(A& self) {
        std::cout << "int." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Using `std::enable_if` here is a bit roundabout. If the primary template admits `typename = std::true_type` as a defaulted parameter then e.g. `typename std::is_pod<T>::type` is a shorter way to achieve the same partial specialization.

Comment: Not bad - but I need to access A member data from FooCaller, so I would have to forward the call yet again to a member function of A. That starts to look very complicated.

Comment: Well, just have a simple `template<class C> using not_ = std::integral_constant<bool, !C::value>;`. Or make it a `struct` for compilers that don't support using aliases yet: `template<class C> struct not_ : std::integral_constant<bool, !C::value>{};` and use that in the partial spec: `FooCaller<not_<std::is_pod<T>>::type>`

Comment: Worst scenario you can use `std::integral_constant<bool, !std::is_pod<T>::value>`.